# Debug Startup of iOS App in Safari Web Inspector

Tags: cordova

I have several issues with the startup of my cordova app which I would like to debug in Web Inspector. The problem is the issues occur before the device appears in Safari's Develop menu. Is there any way to get the web inspector to start before the app actually runs?

Comment: i guess you gotta use console.log to print the errors and start the app in device connected to the mac using xcode. That way you can see the console logs in the xcode debug console.

Answer (score 12):

When the app loads and you can finally debug, use the Reload icon in the dev tools. This will reload the app itself and you'll see any early console messages.

[image: This button]

Comment: cmd+r will also make it reload.